# How to continuously sync/merge two MySQL databases into a third one

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have two MySQL (can also be MariaSQL) databases. They have identical structure. Let's say they have two tables. Customers and Orders.

I need to continuously merge/sync/replicate these two databases into a single one containing data from both. This third database will also have the same structure but some tables will have different primary index. Because Order IDs in the two source databases can collide, I need to create a compound index for the third DB of both Order ID and Customer ID.

I will only read data from the third DB so there is no need to sync changes back to source DBs. Different app is writing data to those two source DBs. This app is not under my control and I cannot change the data or the database structure.

The reason I'm doing this is that I have two data sources and a single app that will access data from those sources. And I have no way to know in which DB is a given customer stored so I need to sync them all into a single DB if I want to avoid searching both.

So the question is: What is the easiest way sync those two databases into one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for multi sourced replication. In MySQL 5.7 there is a pretty simple implementation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html

However, it will not apply any logic.

In 5.6 there is a binlog api, more info: http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/61/Binary%20log%20API_%20A%20Library%20for%20Change%20Data%20Capture%20using%20MySQL%20Presentation.pdf

Traditionally, you would use mysqlbinlog to pull the data from the masters and merge it into the client. This is not so simple because you have to handle things like restarts, crashes, failures etc. It is still doable, I have implemented this in perl.

Comment: Thank you. These should work. I like the simplicity of multi sourced replication but have a question about that. What would happen if an order with ID 7 is updated in the source db. If there are two orders with ID 7 in the replicated DB, will the replication system know which one to update in the replicated db? Or will it update both or a random one?

Comment: You get to figure out all of these issues simply when populating the data :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Are you saying that multi sourced replication is not a workable solution for me? I'm bit confused about whether I should investigate and try it or if it's just not suited for what I want to do. After more research, I'm also considering putting both DBs on the same server and doing SELECTs from both at once and thus eliminatig the need for replication.

Comment: I think the OP wants to replicate the rows from two sources into the a single table, but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value will cause "duplicate key" problems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Orders` has `customer_id` values that are valid on one server, you would have to write *code* to figure out what to do about the conflicting ids from the other server.  You have further complicated the question by requesting "continuous merging".

I have to say "not possible". And "start over" in designing your system(s).

Comment: There are no conflicting customer_id values. These are unique accros the whole system. There are only conflicting order_id values but the Ordes table has also a customer_id column and the combination is globally unique. Unfortunately our external systems updates data in the source databases based solely on the order_id and therfore I assume that a simple replication is not possible. Redesigning the whole structure is not an option in the sort term. I never do selects based on the conflicting ids but I think that the best option might be to do one select on multiple dbs on one server.

Comment: `order_id` is unique within each server?  Is it `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  But not unique between the servers?  Does anything external care if the order_ids are change -- such as adding 1M to one server?

Comment: Yes, they are unique in each server but can collide if they are merged. Its not auto_increment. External systems are adding and modifying orders to each source db.